# How do you add objects into an array from a main method? Also, how do you make a menu in the main method?

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so I have to make a driver for one of my assignments and what I'm testing is my ArrayObject class. The class has a "add" method:

```
private int actualSize; // assume actualSize == 0 for this code
public void add(Object obj)
{
    if(actualSize>=arr.length)
        return;
    arr[actualSize]=obj;
    actualSize++;
}
```

So this adds an object that the user wants when they create the array in the ArrayObject class. Now, I've made an ArrayObjectDriver class and in this class, I need to create a menu where it loops back.
So far:

```
public class ArrayObjectDriver{
    ArrayObject array = new ArrayObject();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int option = selectionMenu();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayObjectDriver drive = new ArrayObjectDriver(); 
        drive.methods(option);
    }

    private static int selectionMenu()
    {
        int optionNumber = 1;
        System.out.println("Menu: ");
        System.out.println("1. Add object to the end of the list");
        return optionNumber;
    }

    private void methods(int option)
    {
        if(option==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your object: ");
            String str = scanner.nextLine(); // putting string for now
            array.add(str);
        }
    }
}
```

That's a snippet of the code of I were to only use the first option. What I'm having trouble with adding an object to the array. I don't know how you would take user input to add an object to the array in a main method. Another problem that occurred was the program itself. I left it as a string to test string input and everytime I would run the program, it would always stop running after it asked me to "Enter my object: ". How do I stop this so it would add a, let's say, string object, to my array? It doesn't add anything to the array.

The next question I have is how you would loop the main method. I tried a recursive approach in the void methods(int option) code and then testing putting the drive.methods(option) code in a while loop but it didn't work. Would I have to call on the selectionMenu() over and over?

EDIT:

- I declared a Scanner.
- I declared the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get user input from the console you can use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class:
`Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );`
It looks like you have a variable scanner, but from the snippet you have posted you have never initialized it.  If you want to loop in your main method you could do something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {

    private static Scanner scanner;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayObject array = new ArrayObject();
        String option = "";
        int selection = selectionMenu();
        while(selection != 3){
            if(selection == 1){
                System.out.println("Enter your object");
                String input = scanner.next();
                array.add(input);
            }else if(selection == 2){
                for(Object o : array){
                    System.out.println("Object value: "+o.toString());
                }
            }

            selection = selectionMenu();
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static int selectionMenu(){
        System.out.println("Menu:");
        System.out.println("\t1. Add object");
        System.out.println("\t2. Print objects");
        System.out.println("\t3. Quit:");
        int option =scanner.nextInt(); 
        return option;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did initialize the scanner but forgot to put it in the snippet. And for the while loop, would it always remain true then and depend on the user to input exit to break it? Also, I can see how the while loop repeats the first option but I need it to loop the entire void method.

Comment: In this case yes.  You could also change it so that instead of using a while(true), you check the input.

Comment: But wouldn't the while loop only loop that one option? How would I loop it so I can get another option input from the user?

Comment: @immmjimmy Modified my answer to show how to handle other options, while still taking user input to add to your array.  Note that I switched to just using java.util.ArrayList as I didn't want to implement an ArrayObject class (if it's not required for the assignment I recommend using one of the standard Java collections).

Comment: I would've used an ArrayList, but the assignment wants us to practice with arrays for now, so we're not allowed to use lists yet. But I can see how it works.

Comment: @immmjimmy I updated to show a working example (if you have ArrayObject) of responding to selection and then taking user input to add to ArrayObject.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, create an ArrayObject class object in main method and pass the reference of the object in your `methods(int option, ArrayObject arrays)` and then you can easily add an object to arrays.

And, for your next question. Why you want to loop the main method, instead just create a for or while loop in the main method.
Something like this:

```
     while(true)
     {
        System.out.println("Menu ");
        System.out.println("1. Option 1 ");
        System.out.println("2. Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice ");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        switch(n)
        {
          case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter your object: ");
                String str = scanner.nextLine(); // putting string for now
                array.add(str);
                break;
           case 2 :
                System.exit(0);  

        }
     }
```

Comment: How would I write the logic for case? I was briefly taught on that.

Comment: case 1 :  System.out.println("Enter your object: ");
              String str = scanner.nextLine(); // putting string for now
              array.add(str); break;

Comment: Would the code wait for user input before breaking?

Comment: yes, definitely. Let us assume user entered 1, then case 1 executed and prompt user to "Enter your Object : "  when user entered a value or string and press enter then only add method is called.

Comment: Oh shoot ok. Because when I tried to do it in my code, it didn't work and it would break the code before taking any input.

Comment: Try once again !! It have to work. Let me know if doesn't work. As I have written the same code in many of my running project and its working fine.

Comment: Ok yeah, it's working now. I guess it didn't work because originally, they were if-else statements.